# Prove that number $\underbrace{11 \ldots1}_{100} \underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{100}$ is product of two consecutive numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that number $\underbrace{11 \ldots1}_{100}$$\underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{100}$ is product of  two consecutive numbers

$\begin{align}\underbrace{11 \ldots1}_{100} \underbrace{22 \ldots2}_{100}&=10^{199}+10^{198}+\ldots+10^{100}+2(10^{99}+10^{98}+\ldots+10+1)\\&=(10^{100}+2)(10^{99}+10^{98}+\ldots+10+1)=(10^{100}+2)\frac{10^{100}-1}{10-1}\end{align}$.

Is this good path or not?

Comment: You need a backslash before underbrace to get what you want.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in re-writing the way you have (though of course I might be missing something).  I'd start small.  Note that $12=3\times 4$.  What about $1122$?  Well, that's $33\times 34$.  Maybe there's a pattern....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply the result below, with $\,a = 10^{100}\!-1,\ n = 3,\,$  using $\,n^2\mid a$

$$\begin{align}
&\dfrac{a+n}{1}\ \dfrac{a}{n^2}\\[.3em]
=\ &\dfrac{a+n}{n}\ \dfrac{a}{n}\\[.3em]
=\ &(b+1)\, b
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are not done because the two factors you exhibited are not consecutive.  For three digits, you have shown $111222=1002\cdot 111$.  You can, however, make one more step and be there.  lulu has given a good hint.

Comment: $111222=333\times334$

Comment: @YadatiKiran:  that is correct, but OP has not demonstrated that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Insert $1=\frac{1}{3}*3$

$$
(10^{100}+2)\frac{1}{3} 3\frac{10^{100}-1}{10-1}\\
x= \frac{10^{100}+2}{3}\\
y=3\frac{10^{100}-1}{10-1} = \frac{10^{100}-1}{3}\\\\
$$